# Making text selectable on hover with css

Tags: html, css

I have a span element that is holding some text. I want to be able to hover over the element and make the text selectable.

The HTML:

```
<span>Text to copy</span>
```

The SCSS:

```
span {  

 &:hover {
   border: 1px #000 solid;
   padding: 2px;
   cursor: text;
 }
}
```

However, I have not been able to copy the text.

I tried adding the 'user-select: text' property to the hover but that does not seem to work on chrome.

Comment: Would there be an issue with making the text always selectable, not just on hover? So you would do `user-select:text` but on the span or text in general?

Comment: That is not working

Comment: When you go into developer tools/the inspector, and you select the element you're trying to make selectable, does the `user-select` property show up at all, or is there something possible overriding it?

Comment: a span element's text is selectable by default.  There is something over riding that default behavior somewhere.  As was mentioned, use the dev tools inspector.

Comment: Actually the span is inside an ember link-to helper component. You can consider it as an a tag if you are not familiar with Ember. I am wondering if that is the cause.

Comment: CSS is concerned with appearance, not behavior - it is a *style* sheet. If you want behavior (like selecting text in reponse to a mouse over event), you'll need to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`user-select:text` property means user can select the text, it does not select the text.

Two ways to achieve that:

1. with the help of `document.execCommand()`

```html
   <span contenteditable="true" onmouseover="this.focus();document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null);">mouse over on text</span>
<br/>
<span>mouse over on text</span>
<br/>
<span contenteditable="true" onmouseover="this.focus();document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null);">content editable</span> - makes the span editable
```

2. with the help of jQuery

Note: `this.select()` works for input and textarea.

```js
$("textarea").mouseover(function(){
  $(this).select();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea>mouseover on text</textarea>
```

Comment: I like the first approach. But it selects all the text on the page. My span element is a repeated element with different text content. I want to be able to focus/hover on individual spans and copy their specific contents.

Comment: I have updated the code, now it will selects only the span text